# How could you notate a measure where you have "cut-off" triplets?

Tags: time-signatures, meter, tuplet

So, let's say you have a measure of 3/4. Like the following:

[image: Measure of 3/4]

Then you have a triplet in the next measure, like this:

[image: Triplet]

How would I "cut off" the last quarter rest from that triplet? I was thinking to create a measure of 2/3, or two "third notes" aka triplets. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Just to make sure I understand what you want.  You have music that is going at, say, 80 quarter notes per minute, and somewhere in the middle you want a measure with 2 quarter notes at 120 quarter notes per minute.

Comment: Is the first measure 3/4 with syncopation, or is it 6/8?

Comment: @user1079505 It says 3/4. And it looks like 3/4. Why do you think it might not be?

Comment: We discussed these time signatures recently. Here, if it's any help: https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/101870/can-any-score-writer-do-irrational-time-signatures

Comment: @OldBrixtonian Because the note grouping used is characteristic for 6/8 rather than 3/4, and because the rhythm would be rather natural in 6/8, and syncopated in 3/4. Of course there is nothing wrong with using syncopation, and such short-hand notation of syncopated rhythm can be sometimes used, given OP is asking about time signatures and notation, it looks like something they may want to double check.

Comment: Your idea is right ZipCreator, but it would be 2/6, not 2/3. You’d use 3 on the bottom if it were *half*-note triplets, but 6 for quarter-note triplets (and 12 for eighth-note triplets). Alternatively, you can do a tempo modulation.

Comment: I don't understand how, in 3/4 time, there can be a triplet worth exactly what a standard 3/4 bar contains. If you mean two equal notes to fill that bar, 6/8 would be a simple answer.

Comment: @user1079505 You say the note-grouping used is characteristic of 6/8 rather than 3/4. It isn't. How ELSE can you write it in 3/4?!

Comment: There is no such thing as a "third note,"  "irrational meters" cultists notwithstanding.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest solution is given by the Wikipedia [Irrational Meters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_signature#Irrational_meters) entry. You would just write it as two half-notes, which, given the <sup>2</sup>/<sub>3</sub> time signature, would be understood as two "thirds-of-a-whole-note".

> for example, one beat in ​4⁄5 is written as a normal quarter note, four quarter notes complete the bar, but the whole bar lasts only ​4⁄5 of a reference whole note, and a beat ​1⁄5 of one (or ​4⁄5 of a normal quarter note).

Another possibility, from Wikipedia's [Tuplet:Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuplet#Notation) entry would be to notate the tuplet using a [3:2] ratio indication, meaning "three of this type of note comprises two beats", but you'd only have two notes present within the tuplet.

Comment: What I meant was that the time signature should be 2/6. Then it's two quarter-note triplets like the OP wanted.

Comment: @PatMuchmore OP indicates 2/3 time but used a quarter-note triplet as his example. So am I understanding correctly that two quarter notes would give 2/6 and two half notes would give 2/3?

Comment: Right, that’s the OP’s mistake: 3rd notes would be half note triplets, sixth notes are quarter note triplets.

Comment: Do you still want to retain '2/3' in the 1st para?

Comment: @Tim Yes, unless my post is incorrect. My intention is to err on the side of the OP meaning "2/3" and that the quarter-note triplet was just to get across the idea of what was being sought.

Answer (score 1):

Thinking "out of the box", if you can allow yourself to change the first measure time signature, you may consider:

```
X: 1  
K: Bb
M: 9/8  
L: 1/16
V:Vc clef=bass
C,3D,3 E,3(D,3 D,3) C,3 | [M: 2/4]  C4B,4 |]
```

or

```
X: 1  
K: Bb
M: 9/8  
L: 1/16
V:Vc clef=bass
C,3D,3E,3 D,6 C,3 | [M: 2/4]  C4B,4 |]
```

This of course depends on the rest of the composition. The dotted eights might be annoying to read, but might be easier than irrational meters.

Comment: Really is easier to read and play if you stick with  3/4 - 2/4 time and add a written instruction as to the change in meter (bpm)

Answer (score 1):

I **think** this is what you're trying to do:

[image]

Comment: Bad notation!  No biscuit!    Notes (post + head + flag) do not accept the concept of a nonbinary base unit

Comment: :-) As a matter of fact Carl, I myself find this *particular* example less appealing, but only 'cos the notes are a bit er... uninformative. I can't see any advantage of the 2/6 bar over a 3/8 one with two dotted quavers, except that the two bars together would then amount to one 9/8 bar. Nonetheless, that's how I personally - not knowing the context - would write it, but I'd add the magic word **riten.** extended by a horizontal line over the two notes, just to stop it sounding like 9/8 and being in any way foot-tappable. *Might* even add a **giusto** over the following bar. There. Biscuit?